# Merging 2 svg images to a new svg image file using python libraries

Tags: python, svg, editing

I want to know if there is any python library available that can merge two svg files to a new svg file. Wherein new svg file has elements from file 1 and file 2 placed next to each other.

Below are the two svg files can be used

File 1:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40pt" height="40pt" viewBox="0 0 40 40" version="1.1">
<g id="surface1">
<path style="fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;" d="M -10 -10 L 10 -10 L 10 10 L -10 10 Z M -10 -10 " transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,20,20)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

File 2:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="40pt" height="40pt" viewBox="0 0 40 40" version="1.1">
<g id="surface1">
<path style="fill-rule:nonzero;fill:rgb(0%,0%,0%);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,0%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;" d="M 10 0 C 10 5.523438 5.523438 10 0 10 C -5.523438 10 -10 5.523438 -10 0 C -10 -5.523438 -5.523438 -10 0 -10 C 5.523438 -10 10 -5.523438 10 0 Z M 10 0 " transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,20,20)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

svg1 = ET.parse('test-1.svg').getroot()
svg2 = ET.parse('test-2.svg').getroot()

merged_svg = ET.Element('svg')

merged_svg.attrib = svg1.attrib

for elem in svg1:
    merged_svg.append(elem)
for elem in svg2:
    merged_svg.append(elem)

ET.ElementTree(merged_svg).write('merged.svg')
```